# Problems with variables inside styles using pug

Tags: node.js, styles, pug

I'm building a little app with NodeJS and Pug as engine.
I just want to insert a variable inside an element style, but can't find the way to make it work. Here is the code:

```
- var grados = 45;
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-up(style={transform:'rotate(#{grados}deg)'})
```

I think the problem is the parenthesis from the transform attribute, I tried it with another simpler approach like `color:grados` (`- var grados = 'red'`) and it worked fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you've stumbled upon a common issue in Pug: Support for attribute interpolation has been dropped, so that syntax is no longer supported. See [the page in the Pug docs relating to this](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation). There is no 'clean' solution to fix this, other than simply building the attribute string with string concatenation:

```
- var grados = 45;
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-up(style={transform:'rotate(' + grados + 'deg)'})
```

Comment: Thank you gandreadis, your solution fixed the poblem, works perfect!